# Convert an INT Column to H:MM Format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a column which contains integer value of a quantity of time for example 60 mins, 90mins, 200mins etc to HH:MM Format. I have tried various formulas related to CAST() AND CONVERT() SUCH AS:

```
1. CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),C.Quantity/60) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),C.Quantity%60)

2.REPLACE(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), 
        (SUM(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(Minute, 0,C.Quantity), 0))/60) + 
        ((SUM(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(Minute, 0,C.Quantity), 0)) % 60))),'.',':')

3.CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),C.Quantity/60,0),108)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),C.Quantity%60,0),108)

4.CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),C.Quantity/60) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),C.Quantity%60)

5.CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @FirstDate, @LastDate), 0), 114)
```

Comment: mysql  != (MS)sql-server. so remove unrelated tags. And never use ASAP in your question

Comment: What should happen if/when it exceeds 1440 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD` onto a starting time of `00:00:00`

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(minute, t.Quantity, CAST('00:00:00' AS time))
FROM YourTable t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=179ec6464e95e81b8266a52ea866400a)

Comment: Hello. It shows this error
"Explicit conversion from data type float to time is not allowed."

Comment: Cannot replicate this error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b911457740343b4df022a053c8a5185

Comment: @user19631601 But you explicitly wrote that your column is an INT. Even minor details matter - but using an inappropriate datatype will always allow invalid values that you must cleanse or ignore before attempting to use in a rational manner.